# How can I use values from a Pandas data frame in a calcul?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame. In the `A` columns there are ints like `[1, 5, 3]`, and in the `B` columns there are string like `["abcdef", "ghijklmno", "qwertyuiop"]`

I want to create a `C` columns with the columns `B` first char according to the columns `A`. In my example I want the `C` columns to be like `["a", "ghijk", "qwe" ]`

I tried:

```
data_frame['C'] = data_frame.B.str[:data_frame["A"]]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set use a lambda function and set the axis = 1 to use column A to set the string length of B

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [1, 5, 3,],
    'B' : ["abcdef", "ghijklmno", "qwertyuiop"]
})
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['B'][:x['A']], axis = 1)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try looping over the columns:

```
df['C'] = [b[:a] for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```